# WPF how to highlight and select an item in code in comobox

Tags: wpf, combobox

Hi all i need help wih my combobox. Iam quite new in the WPF world.
Ihave an combobox that the itemsource is binding with the following items:

```
Red
Green
Blue
Yellow
```

I want to select like "Red" in the code behind then the combobox will highligt "Red" and "Red" is selected. How can i do this in code thanks for advice.
And sorry for my bad english.

Comment: OK i solved this with:

                int index = -1;
                foreach(Color mdoc in Colors) {
                    index++;
                    if(color.Description.Equals(db.colors.Description)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }

comboboc1.SelectedIndex = index;

Is there any better solutions i think thats to much code for an simple task. please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind combobox's value property to description, and the item will be highligted after setting value

Comment: Thanks for the help but i dont get what you mean. Can you please give an example.